What is the probability that out of six objects, two are not adjacent?
The book by S. Epp "Discrete Mathematics with applications", 5th edition, contains the following exercise:

Six new employees, two of whom are married to
each other, are to be assigned six desks that are
lined up in a row. If the assignment of employees
to desks is made randomly, what is the probability that the married couple will have nonadjacent
desks? (Hint: The event that the couple have nonadjacent desks is the complement of the event that
they have adjacent desks.)

The book also contains the answer: $2/3$. Please, help me understand why my solution is not correct and explain how one may reason correctly about this problem.
My solution:
Suppose $a, b, c, d, e, f$ are employees. Suppose also that $a$ and $b$ are married. Then the total number of permutations of all six employees without any restriction is $6!$. The number of permutations where $a$ and $b$ are adjacent is $5!$: treat both $a$ and $b$ as one whole. Then the number of permutations where $a$ and $b$ are not adjacent is $6! - 5! = 600$. Then the probability that out of all possible permutations, $a$ and $b$ are not adjacent is $600 / 6! \approx 83\%$.

You forgot to account for the relative positions of $a$ and $b$ within the block.

You're undercounting the permutations with $a$ and $b$ adjacent by a factor of 2.
abcdef and bacdef, for example, are different permutations you're counting as the same.
If you double the 5! before subtracting that will fix it.

Another way to get the correct answer
is to put $A$ and $B$ in the gaps between $CDEF$
$.C .D . E . F .$
Then you can directly compute $Pr = \frac{5\times 4\times 4!}{6!} = \frac23$

The number of permutations where $a, b$ are adjacent to each other is not $5!$, so you are undercounting. You have assumed $[ab]$ to be a joint block travelling across permutations together, however, you did not account for the fact that $[ab]$ may travel together as $[ba]$ as well.
This simply means rewriting the number of permutations where the couple is adjacent to be $5!\times 2$ because all the $[ba]$ permutations are the same in number as the $[ab]$ permutations.
